# Equivalence Set, Subsets

Tags: equivalence-relations

Just a quick question:

If a = [A] and a belongs to N (set of all natural numbers) doesn't that mean that A is a subset of N?

The reason I'm asking this is because I'm trying to prove the theorem that the set of all natural numbers is closed under addition.

The definition of addition that I have is the following:
Let a, b, c be natural numbers. We write a + b = c if and inly if there exists sets A and B such that a = [A], b = [B], A intersection B is nullset and c = [A union B]

I was thinking if a and b are natural numbers then A and B are subsets of N, and so is their union, which makes c also a natural number.

Thank you

Comment: $a=[A]$ or $a\in[A]$?

Comment: a = [A] where a belongs to N

Comment: Okay, so I'm *very* unclear as to what is $[A]$ and what is $a$. Also, what *exactly* do you mean by the set of natural numbers? Is this is the context of set theory, where we take $\omega$? Or is this in a different context, where numbers are not treated as sets (not in particular anyway)? Or is it that $\Bbb N$ is in fact a subset of $\Bbb C$ when constructed via some canonical method from $\omega$?

Comment: a is a equivalence set on A. Well, N = {1, 2, 3, ...} :)

Comment: What is an equivalence set? Do you mean an equivalence *relation*, the set of ordered pairs, or do you mean a partition of $A$? Or is this a particular equivalence *class* of $A$? Or is this ... what?

Comment: You are not answering *my* questions. Is $1=\{\varnothing\}$ and $2=\{1\}$ and $3=\{1,2\}$ and so on? If not, what does that mean for a set to be a natural number at all?

Comment: Asaf, sorry I answered you wrong. I updated the question.

Comment: Now it's slightly better; but you still haven't answered my questions. What **are** natural numbers for you? And what do you mean by $[A]$? Do you mean $|A|$? The cardinality of $A$?

Comment: These are the natural numbers N = {1, 2, 3...}. 1={∅} and 2={1} and 3={1,2} etc... I'm not sure to be honest about the latter, I read it from the book.

Comment: Perhaps it is better to be sure about your foundations, before setting to prove something which is *very* foundational (i.e. depends on your interpretation of certain notions into the mathematical universe).

Comment: Wait, I think 1 = {a}, 2 = {a, b}, 3 = {a, b, c} etc

Comment: Yeah, I give up. You should first sit and understand the definition of a natural number before tackling the two questions that you have asked about them. As I said, and as comments to your previous question said, this is a foundational issue which depends on how you define the natural numbers (and to answer "Well, 1,2,3,..." is *not* a valid answer to this question. At all).